# access terraform modules in different root directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-modules

[I have this file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZrKB.png)
that contains 2 root modules that I apply from them separately.
I want to access in one module module output from different root directory

```
module "lambda" {
  source                           = "../../modules/lambda"

  environment                      = var.environment
  clean-bucket-name                = "../flow-components/module.s3.clean-bucket-name"
  infected-bucket-name             = "../flow-components/module.s3.infected-bucket-name"
  after-classification-bucket-name = module.s3.after-classification-bucket-name
}
```

this is two examples of trying to access the module.

the first one just give this string
and the second one gives me this error

```
│ Error: Reference to undeclared module
│
│   on lambda.tf line 8, in module "lambda":
│    8:   after-classification-bucket-name = module.s3.after-classification-bucket-name
│
│ No module call named "s3" is declared in the root module.
```

this is the second module

```
module "s3" {
  source      = "../../modules/s3"
  environment = var.environment
}
```

and the output file of that module

```
output "before-av-bucket-name" {
  value = aws_s3_bucket.before-av-bucket.bucket
}

output "clean-bucket-name" {
  value = aws_s3_bucket.clean-bucket.bucket
}

output "infected-bucket-name" {
  value = aws_s3_bucket.infected-bucket.bucket
}

output "after-classification-bucket-name" {
  value = aws_s3_bucket.after-classification-bucket.bucket
}
```

the file structure

```
├───environment
│   ├───flow-components
│   │   ├───provider
│   │   ├───s3
│   ├───lambdas
│   │   ├───provider
│   │   ├─── lambda
└───modules
    ├───lambda
    └───s3
```

How can I access the output of this module?

Comment: Please add the second module and the way you are calling it and the directory structure as text.

Comment: Are you calling both modules in the same root module? I guess not. If so, you cannot do that. The easiest way to achieve what you want is probably to use one of the data sources to fetch the bucket name. The other option would be to use terragrunt.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using valid Terraform syntax. To reference the output of a module you don't specify that as a file path. You have the correct syntax right there in the `after-classification-bucket-name` attribute, so I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the other two attributes.

The correct syntax is:

```
module "lambda" {
  source                           = "../../modules/lambda"

  environment                      = var.environment
  clean-bucket-name                = module.s3.clean-bucket-name
  infected-bucket-name             = module.s3.infected-bucket-name
  after-classification-bucket-name = module.s3.after-classification-bucket-name
}
```

Comment: I am trying to access module output that originates in a different root module but as it seems it is not possible

Comment: If they are in different root modules, in other words you created them by running `terraform apply` in a different directory from the one you are running `terraform apply` now, then what you are trying to do is not possible, and you should instead use data sources as suggested in another comment.